# Why id of item is not visible in the recyclerview adapter?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I was writing a recyclerview by using view binding features, but I am not be able to access the id of the item which is existing in the item.xml file in the project. Here is codes of adapter and item.xml file.

adapter:

```
class RecyclerviewAdapter(val Data:List<Data>):RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerviewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    class ViewHolder(binding: ItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = ItemBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return Data.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.
    }
}
```

item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/temperaturec"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/temperaturef"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/summary"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I want to access the id of texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `binding` constructor parameter into a property using `val`:

```
class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

Then you can use it to access the views:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.binding.date.text = /* for example: */ Data[position].date
}
```

You don't need the actual ID of the view that you asked for since you're using view binding.